# Visual Studio 2010 NuGet package manager console: Nothing happens on pressing enter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I did search the internet and stackoverflow regarding a solution of my problem: After installing NugGet, during the very first try to use it via the package manager console, I type in "Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json" and then I press "enter". The curser jumps to the new line, but nothing happens. The behaviour is the same for every other command I tried, e.g. "get-help NuGet".

This issue is documented: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/8331, however, not anserwed.

What I tried so far: restarting VS2010 like several people recommended when having errors. Reinstall NuGet via extension manager of VS2010. Check if extension manager has internet access (I am behind a proxy).

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the NuGet GUI work? What does Tools | Options | NuGet Package Manager show?

Comment: Tools | Options | NuGet Package Manager > Name: "nuget.org", Source: "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/". Check mark is set. However, when using the NuGet Dialog (["GUI"](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/Package-Manager-Dialog)) it did work and I could install the package. Thanks!